# Break on syscalls only from target process in kernel windbg debugging

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg, windows-kernel, kernel-mode

I'm debugging a user-mode process **"myprocess.exe"** which has a long running operations, constantly doing system calls to kernel mode, how can i break on syscalls, for example: i want to break and examine all `ZwCreateEvent` calls, that are called from **"myprocess.exe"** ?
If i just do `bp nt!ZwCreateEvent` i get thousands of breakpoints from across the system, not related to the **"myprocess.exe"** and it is impbossible to catch ones that are coming from **"myprocess.exe"**

I know that there are conditional breakpoints, but i don't have a specific parameter to which i can bind myself ( the one with constant known value or string )

Comment: `bp /p` to break on a specific process (see [bp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bp--bu--bm--set-breakpoint-) documentation)

Answer (score 2):

You can set kernel breakpoints per process using the `bp /p` command ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bp--bu--bm--set-breakpoint-)):

> /p EProcess (Kernel-mode only) Specifies a process that is associated
> with this breakpoint. EProcess should be the actual address of the
> EPROCESS structure, not the PID. The breakpoint is triggered only if
> it is encountered in the context of this process.

To get the `EPROCESS` structure (which represents a process object in kernel land), you can issue the [`!process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-process) command:

Example with notepad:

```
0: kd> !process 0 0 notepad.exe
PROCESS ffffbe8e593d3080
    SessionId: 14  Cid: 74bc    Peb: 2d7c91c000  ParentCid: 8a94
    DirBase: a2faeb002  ObjectTable: ffffa981f4ce3a40  HandleCount: 246.
    Image: notepad.exe
```

The hexadecimal number right at the top of the output (`ffffbe8e593d3080` above) is the address of the EPROCESS structure. If you have more than one process with the same name, you can discriminate between them using the `Cid` (otherwise known a PID, Process identifier).

Setting a BP:

```
0: kd> bp /p ffffbe8e593d3080 nt!ZwCreateEvent
```

Debugging a userland process in kernel mode is sometimes a bit contrived. I'd suggest to debug your process using windbg in user mode and setting a breakpoint at the user / kernel boundary (that is, in `ntdll.dll`), simply:

```
0:004> bp ntdll!ZwCreateEvent
```

Note that in this case (from a user-mode debugger) you're setting a breakpoint in the function that performs the syscall (transitioning to kernel mode):

```
0:004> u ntdll!ZwCreateEvent
ntdll!NtCreateEvent:
00007ffa`d1d8d950 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx
00007ffa`d1d8d953 b848000000      mov     eax,48h
00007ffa`d1d8d958 f604250803fe7f01 test    byte ptr [SharedUserData+0x308 (00000000`7ffe0308)],1
00007ffa`d1d8d960 7503            jne     ntdll!NtCreateEvent+0x15 (00007ffa`d1d8d965)
00007ffa`d1d8d962 0f05            syscall
00007ffa`d1d8d964 c3              ret
```

Obviously, you won't be able to step in kernel mode from there.

Comment: just an aside well most of the times after hitting ntdll!xxxx you can immediately set bp nt!xxxx and do a single step in (t or trace and you will normally be in process context)